# HTTPGet response displayed in email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, httprequest, rest-service

I wrote a rest service using cloud page. However, whenever i try to use it in an email, the response payload is not showing up correctly. I've tried treatascontent but same thing happens.

[http://www.devsutd.com/writing-a-rest-service-using-cloud-pages/](http://Writing%20a%20rest%20service%20using%20cloud%20page)

Ampscript in email

```
%%[
Set @content = HTTPGet("http://cloud.sfmc.test.com/ssjs?param1=param") ]%%

%%=v(@content)=%%
```

Response in email

> �mQak�0������
>   ����B7�[�m���5퇕R4I���:Ϻ,3!�}r��q��=��

Answer (score 3):

I got this working using the code below:

```
%%[
var @postBody, @error, @status, @response

set @status = HTTPPost2('http://cloud.sfmc.test.com/ssjs?param1=param','text/html', '', true, @output,@respheader, 'Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br')

]%%
Output: %%=v(@output)=%%
```

Output looks like this

```
Output: {"status": "ok","Response": {"shortURL":"test"}
```

If anyone has a better solution, please let me know.